# how to create monthly folder from 2020 to 2024 in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to auto create monthly folder from 2020 to 2024.

For instance,

- 2020

  ```
   -Jan
   -Feb
    ...
   -Dec
  ```
- 2021

  ```
   -Jan
    ...
   -Dec
  ```
- 2022

  ```
   -Jan
   ...
   -Dec
  ```

all the way to 2024.

I have tried with my code -

```
$d = 1..12|%{(get-date).AddMonths(-6+$_).ToString("MMM yyyy")} 
$d | % {(new-Item -Path C:\testmonth\$_ -ItemType Directory)}
```

I want to know is there a better coding to auto create monthly folder.

Much appreciated folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple nested loop for this:

```
$Path   = 'C:\testmonth'
$Months = [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames
for ($y = 2020; $y -lt 2025; $y++) {
    for ($m = 0; $m -lt 12; $m++) {
        $folder = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath ('{0}\{1}' -f $y, $Months[$m])
        $null = New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: I will take this solution, it is so fast. Not sure why though. What if I replace the $Months = [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames to $Months = "Jan, Feb, Mar ... Dec" and use the $Months[0], Months[1], Months[2]... Months[11]. Is that the same? has the solution the same speed? thanks

Comment: @JamesNEW Yes, you can of course always define the array yourself, but if you do `$Months = "Jan, Feb, Mar ... Dec"`, then you are creating a single string and you will need to split the values on the comma (and trim off the spaces). Better then do `$Months = "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" ... "Dec"` so it will be an array immediately. But why do this when the system already knows these names (for many different cultures)? This is the fastest because [1] it doesn't use piping and [2] it doesn't call `Get-Date` in each iteration. P.S. If you like my solution best, please mark it 'done'.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($year in 2020..2024)
{
    foreach ($month in 1..12)
    {
        $mon = Get-Date -Date $year-$month -Format "MMM"
        mkdir $year\$mon -Force
    }
}
```

mkdir -Force will make parent and subfolders in one go.

Comment: thank you for providing the solution. it works!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to loop the years as well. So get all the years.

```
$y = 1..4 | ForEach-Object { (get-date).AddYears(-1+$_).ToString("yyyy") }
```

Excuse my compulsion to change % = ForEach-Object. You are welcome to change it back.

Then get the months as you did.

```
$d = 1..12| ForEach-Object { (get-date).AddMonths(-6+$_).ToString("MMM") }
```

Now you need to loop the years and the months. The trick is to store the year (current values) before looping the days using the $_ (current month).

This looks like so.

```
$y | ForEach-Object {
         $currentYear = $_
         (new-Item -Path C:\testmonth\$_ -ItemType Directory)
         $d | ForEach-Object {(new-Item -Path C:\testmonth\$currentYear\$_ -ItemType Directory)}
```

}

Comment: thank you for your contribution. I have learnt a lot.

Comment: Pleasure @JamesNEW - we are all learning together.